# Show that the restriction of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ for every line passing through the origin is continuous.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(0)=0$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$, when $(x,y) \ne0$. Show that $f$ is not continuous at the origin, but that the restriction of $f$ for every line passing through the origin is continuous.

It's easy to show that $f$ is not continuous at the origin by letting $y=\sqrt{x}$ for which $f(x,\sqrt{x}) = \frac12$ and letting $y=\sqrt{2x}$ for which $f(x,\sqrt{2x}) = \frac25$. However I'm not fully understanding what they mean by restricing $f$ for every line passing thourgh the origin? What does this actually mean?

Comment: Take $y=mx$ with $m\in\Bbb R$ arbitray PLUS $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the restriction of $f$ to every set $\{(x,kx)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, as well as to the set $\{(0,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ is continuous.

Comment: $k$ is just an arbitrary scalar so this should be possible to do with $(\varepsilon, \delta)$?

Comment: Bounding $|\frac{x^2k}{x^2 + (kx)^4}|$ doesn't seem intuitive.

Comment: The restriction of $f$ to $\{(0,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ is the null function. Therefore, it is continuous. And, on the line $\{(x,kx)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, we just have the map$$x\mapsto\begin{cases}\frac{mx^3}{x^2+m^4x^4}=\frac{mx}{1+m^4x^2}&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0,\end{cases}$$which is continuous at $0$, since$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{mx}{1+m^4x^2}=0.$$